# Why does the browser resubmit form when you refresh the page, and when you click back, and then forward?

Tags: forms, browser

I understand that the browser resubmits form when you a) refresh the page after submitting and b) when you click back, and then click forward. To avoid confusing the user, server side code should implement the [Post/Redirect/Get design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), where you respond to a POST with a redirect, rather than a render.

But why does the browser do this? The user doesn't expect that behavior, and I don't see any technical reasons to do so.